# When not to use -r with cp?

Tags: linux, terminal, command

I have been using the cp command frequently and I always use the -r option without really knowing why it's needed. What are some cases where you would want to forego the -r option, or would using the -r option in those cases not cause any problems? I'm thinking the only time you wouldn't use it would be in the case of copying a single file?

I tried Googling -r Linux and I know it stands for recursive. My understanding of recursion is that it is a function that calls itself, or something inside something else.

Comment: @Cairnarvon by typing man cp into the terminal? I did that and it doesn't even mention -r...

Answer (score 0):

The `-r` flag in `cp` command is needed when you are copying directories, not files. Without it, it throws you `cp: omitting directory ....` when try to copy a directory

If there are too many subfiles and subdirectories in directory which you are copying and they are not needed to be copied, than it can lasts longer to complete the copying than only copying what is really needed. For example:

You have a React.js webapp project in `webapp` directory, with webapp has many dependencies installed in `node_modules` directory and you want to copy it somewhere elsewhere. First assumption would be to do

```
cp -r webapp somewhere-else
```

but this one will copy all the files, including the mentioned `node_modules` directory, which is not needed to copy if you don't want to run the project or you want to copy only source codes of webapp then it's more clever to copy only `src` subdirectory like this

```
cp -r webapp/src somewhere-else
```

Hope this helps a little bit :)